# Actionbar Sherlock title shows for a sec at first run

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, title

As i mentioned in title of question I want to completely remove title from actionbar but at first run (when I run it from eclipse) title shows for a while and it's not what I want

in the onCreate method I've add this 2 line of code and its work but LATE!!

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

may this 2 pics help u understand me

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why do you need the first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your theme to 'no action bar' in your manifest, then apply your normal theme in code after set contentview!

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar"
```

and then.

```
    this.setTheme(R.style.myTheme); 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: No problem! make sure you click the check mark next to my answer if it works for you :)

Comment: definitely! I will do that

Answer (score 1):

While your code hides actionBar Title, the title will still be displayed while your activity is loading and before you remove the title in your code.

I think a better solution if you want to remove title from actionbar in all of your activities from the start is to do it by setting a theme and override the actionbar style.

To do this you have to create a style in your styles.xml and use this as your application theme e.g.

```
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item
            <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
        </style>
        <style name="AppTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
            <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle.TitleTextStyle</item>
            <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle.TitleTextStyle</item>
        </style>
        <style name="AppTheme.ActionBarStyle.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
            <item name="android:textSize">0dp</item>
            <item name="textSize">0sp</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">#00000000</item>
            <item name="textColor">#00000000</item>
        </style>
```

or another example:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:displayOptions" tools:ignore="NewApi">useLogo|showHome</item>
        <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
    </style>
```

These Code samples were taken from some of my projects where i use actionbarsherlock so you may have to edit it according to your needs.

Hope it helps.